# How to click on a div from console application

Tags: c#, console

I have a c# console application. On running the application, it should launch internet explorer and go to a specific website and also click on a div with id "Record"

Comment: Show what you have tried so far ;)

Comment: You should better use `Selenium` control for this purpose and it can be used with `Console` application, there is another control `WebBrowser` which you cannot use within `Console` app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal recommendation is to use the C# binding for the [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) Web Driver with the InternetExplorerDriver. This allows you to run Internet Explorer, navigate to a page, and then perform an action based on the HTML of the page.

This would basically let you do something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://YouURLorFilename.html");
IWebElement div = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Record"));
div.Click();
```

This is what I used for a project of mine a while ago and it worked well but I'm not sure if the API is still the same so you can refer to the documentation [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) in case it has changed.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much.It really worked.....It navigated to the page by getting the div id. In the new page, I want to click on the first cell of a table. do you have any clue about that?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. You could do the same thing to find a cell. Using `driver.FindElement(By.Id("YourCellNameHere"))`; might work if the cell if uniquely named otherwise you would need to use xpath to find the cell. I would need to see the HTML of the page in order to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

you had better to use webBrowser contrl, so you need add winform library .